# How to write a unit test for a method with a completion handler that returns data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, nsurlsession, nsurlrequest

I'm stuck trying to figure out how to write a unit test for such a method using OCMock. Can someone help me with it?

```
- (void)executeRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(id responseData, NSError *error))completionHandler
{
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if (error)
        {
            NSLog(@"Network error occurred: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) { completionHandler(nil, error);
            });
            return;
        }
    if ([response isKindOfClass:NSHTTPURLResponse.class])
    {
        NSInteger statusCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];
        if (statusCode != 200)
        {
            NSLog(@"Network error occurred. Status code: %ld", (long)statusCode);
            return;
        }
    }
        completionHandler(data, nil);
    }];
    [dataTask resume];
}
```

Comment: Add the test (assert methods) to the completion handler perhaps? For instance set up the test so that the request will fail and then test that the completion handler is called with (nil, error)

Comment: Maybe you could write some code example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use OCMArg with checkWithBlock or invokeBlockWithArgs to test completions handlers. Here an example:

1. Create a XCTestCase subclass by click command+N:

[image: New_file]

2. Add properties for testable instance and necessary mocks:

   ```
   @interface SomeClassTests : XCTestCase

   @property (nonatomic, strong) SomeClass *testableInstance;
   @property (nonatomic, strong) NSURLSession *mockSession;
   @property (nonatomic, strong) NSURLRequest *mockRequest;
   @property (nonatomic, strong) NSHTTPURLResponse *mockResponse;

   @end
   ```
3. Setup properties:

   ```
   - (void)setUp
   {
       [super setUp];
       self.testableInstance = [SomeClass new];
       self.mockSession = OCMClassMock([NSURLSession class]);
       self.mockRequest = OCMClassMock([NSURLRequest class]);
       self.mockResponse = OCMClassMock([NSHTTPURLResponse class]);
       OCMStub(ClassMethod([(id)self.mockSession sharedSession])).andReturn(self.mockSession);
   }
   ```
4. Don't forget to clean up at tear down:

   ```
   - (void)tearDown
   {
       [(id)self.mockSession stopMocking];
       self.mockResponse = nil;
       self.mockRequest = nil;
       self.mockSession = nil;
       self.testableInstance = nil;
       [super tearDown];
   }
   ```
5. Let's test the case when an error is occurs:

   ```
   - (void)testWhenErrorOccuersThenCompletionWithSameError
   {
       // arrange
       NSError *givenError = [[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:@"Domain" code:0 userInfo:nil];
       OCMStub([self.mockSession dataTaskWithRequest:[OCMArg any] completionHandler:([OCMArg invokeBlockWithArgs:@"", self.mockResponse, givenError, nil])]);

       void (^givenCompletion)(id  _Nonnull, NSError * _Nonnull) = ^void(id  _Nonnull responseData, NSError * _Nonnull resultError) {
           // assert
           XCTAssertNil(responseData);
           XCTAssertEqual(resultError, givenError);
       };

       // act
       [self.testableInstance executeRequest:self.mockRequest withCompletionHandler:givenCompletion];
   }
   ```

So we will sure that if some error occurs then the completion handler will invokes with same error at the argument.

6. Let's test when we get some bad status code:

   ```
   - (void)testWhenBadStatusCodeThenReturnWithoutCompletion
   {
       // arrange
       OCMStub([self.mockResponse statusCode]).andReturn(403);
       OCMStub([self.mockSession dataTaskWithRequest:[OCMArg any] completionHandler:([OCMArg checkWithBlock:^BOOL(id param) {
           void (^passedCompletion)(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) = param;
           passedCompletion(nil, self.mockResponse, nil);
           return YES;
       }])]);

       void (^givenCompletion)(id  _Nonnull, NSError * _Nonnull) = ^void(id  _Nonnull responseData, NSError * _Nonnull resultError) {
           // assert
           XCTFail("Shouldn't be reached");
       };

       // act
       [self.testableInstance executeRequest:self.mockRequest withCompletionHandler:givenCompletion];
   }
   ```
7. And finally lets test when we actually get data:

   ```
   - (void)testWhenSuccesThenCompletionWithSameData
   {
       // arrange
       NSData *givenData = [NSData data];
       OCMStub([self.mockResponse statusCode]).andReturn(200);
       OCMStub([self.mockSession dataTaskWithRequest:[OCMArg any] completionHandler:([OCMArg checkWithBlock:^BOOL(id param) {
           void (^passedCompletion)(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) = param;
           passedCompletion(givenData, self.mockResponse, nil);
           return YES;
       }])]);

       void (^givenCompletion)(id  _Nonnull, NSError * _Nonnull) = ^void(id  _Nonnull responseData, NSError * _Nonnull resultError) {
           // assert
           XCTAssertEqual(responseData, givenData);
       };

       // act
       [self.testableInstance executeRequest:self.mockRequest withCompletionHandler:givenCompletion];
   }
   ```

If you will switch on a coverage then you will see that such test fully cover testable code:

[image: Coverage]